# Ajax returns data but shows undefined when fetching the param value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below ajax which is returning the data as {"param1": "value1"}. When I try to print the value of param1 by using data.param1, it returns undefined. There is only one value in the data. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
    $.ajax({
    'type': "POST",
    'url': "${someresourceURL}",
    // data received is [{"param1": "value1"}]
    'success': function (data) {
       console.log(data);   // returns [Object Object]
       console.log(data.param1); returns undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof data)` spit out?

Comment: It returns string

Comment: If `console.log(data)` shows `[object Object]`, then that is literally the string being returned from the API and it generally means something has gone wrong on the server-side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it must be parsed using JSON before you can use it as JS Dictionary

###### Route 1 (Manually doing it)

```js
    $.ajax({
    'type': "POST",
    'url': "${someresourceURL}",
    // data received is [{"param1": "value1"}]
    'success': function (data) {

        console.log(typeof data)    // String

        d = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(typeof d)       // Object (array)
        console.log(typeof d[0])    // Object (dict)

        console.log(d[0]['param1']);// Returns 'value1'
    }
});
```

###### Route 2 (Signify Return is JSON from the Backend)

- You're probably going to have to google yours specifically
- Ajax will then run `JSON.parse()` automatically and data will be a dictionary

###### PHP

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

###### Python/Django

```py
return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(data),
    content_type="application/json"
)
```

Comment: thanks, but what if the data received is [{"param1":"value1"}]. Will it be the same approach?

Comment: yep! As long as the received data can be parsed by Json it'll work. You'll just have to do `d[0]` to get to the dictionary (sorry I missed that it was a array+dict, I thought it was just a dict) + I updated my original code

Answer (score 0):

seems to work ok, do you need to deserialize the response?

```js
var foo = {"param1": "value1"};
console.log(foo);
console.log(foo.param1);
var bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))
console.log(bar)
console.log(bar.param1);
```

Comment: yeah, but it is still showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

you're missing `dataType: 'json'`

```js
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '${someresourceURL}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }
} );
```